# Need help to find out WAVE file's coding

Tags: audio, wav, codec

I'm modding a game and need some help with a WAVE file that I've been trying to change. It seems like that the game has used some kind of weird coding and I can't get any program to regocinize it correctly. I tried to open it up in hex editor, but the Codec ID points to normal PCM file, however playing it results only white noise. I got the best results by opening the file as RAW VOX ADPCM in Audacity, but the audio is still very messy and distorted.

Also, theres an older game by the same creators which has the exactly same files except that they are normal WAVE files, so I was able to provide a comparison:

Unknown coding: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gvlqu2ryu8jwfe3/ColumnCrumble.snd
Normal coding: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3lo2m0wdg43b0q1/ColumnCrumble.wav

Comment: I tend to use a program called SOX to identify and convert audio file formats (http://sox.sourceforge.net/). In this case, though, the `soxi` command says that both files have the same encoding: 16-bit/44.1 kHz/ 16-bit Signed Integer PCM. So, I'm stumped. I did notice that the second file is very short (1/4 the size of the first). Is that a hint that could help you figure out what's going on?  Good luck.

Comment: What game do these files come from? Tony Hawk's Underground, perchance?

Comment: @MultimediaMike Yeah, they come from Tony Hawk's Underground 2 PC version.

Answer (score 2):

It's highly likely the encoded file ADPCM since:

1. as @dB mentions, the .snd file is 1/4 the size and ADPCM is 4-bits/sample vs. 16 for regular PCM.
2. It resembles the expected result when played as ADPCM in audacity.

The distortion you're experiencing might just be a limitation of ADPCM. PCM is able to swing around at a high frequency (2^16 per sample). ADPCM is only able to swing 2^4 per sample and so is slew rate limited. Also, looking at the spectrum of the .wav file, there is quite a bit of high frequency content.

Finally, if you were to patch up the malformed wave format in the encoded file's header so that it indicated ADPCM, it would probably play okay in most players.

Comment: I tried modifying the compressed file's header to use codec IDs 0x0002  (MS ADPCM) and 0x0011 (IMA ADPCM) and neither worked. I also believe the file contains some sort of 4:1 ADPCM compression, but it may take a little more effort to sort of the exact format. Game companies are fond of creating 1-off formats like this.

Comment: @MultimediaMike Yeah, I have tried modifying the headers as well but with no good results. Actually, I think that the closest codec would be Xbox ADPCM (ID 69), since most of the files for Tony Hawk's Underground 2 PC edition are ported from the Xbox version. Also, on www.thmods.com there's one guy that knows the file format completely and can convert normal WAVs to it but seems like that he doesnt wanna talk about it to others :/ Soo yeah.. I guess I'm pretty much out of luck?

Comment: @justoneguy Not really. Me and numerous other people love figuring out multimedia puzzles like this. Was that ID 69 or 0x0069?

Comment: @MultimediaMike Okay, nice to hear that other people are interested in this as well ;) Oh yeah, and the ID is 0x0069. Also heres an [Xbox ADPCM codec](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6me69ahj6uqp3sx/Xbox%20ADPCM%20Codec%20%28x86%29%2064-bit.zip) if you need one. And then an [audio file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gug5cci53y1cfzz/GrindMetal02.pcm) copied straightly from the Xbox version of the game. Hope that helps!